# Mysql save PHP variables to table

Tags: php, mysql

I have a very specific problem

I want to save / load two variables to database, and the third variable use as identificator

My current -not working- code:

```
$sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO time (meno, minuty, sekundy) VALUES('$firstName','$minutes','$seconds')");
if (mysql_error()) die('Error, insert query failed');
```

What I want in the nutshell: When I log with name (etc Roman[$firstName variable]), it will load a previous  $minutes and $seconds numbers, and save every (etc minute) new one (it is a timer, so save a time)

I hope you understand

Thanks for your time, I aprreciade it

My current timer.php

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=Windows-1250');    
$firstName = $_POST['firstname'];

?>


<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=Windows-1250" />
<title>Timing Stránka</title>
        <script>
            let startTime, endTime;
            $(window).on('load', () => {
                startTime = new Date();
            });

            function time_elapsed() {
                endTime = new Date();
                let timeDiff = endTime - startTime;
                let timeSpent = timeConversion(timeDiff);
                const formData = new FormData();
                formData.append('timeSpent', timeSpent);

/* The line below is used to send data to the server-side. This way is reliable than using AJAX to send the data especially in cases when you are listening for an unload event. You can read more about navigator.sendBeacon() in MDN's site. */
                navigator.sendBeacon('db.php', formData);
            }

            function timeConversion(time) {
                let seconds = (time / 1000).toFixed(1);
                let minutes = (time / (1000 * 60)).toFixed(1);
                let hours = (time / (1000 * 60 * 60)).toFixed(1);
                let days = (time / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)).toFixed(1);
                if (seconds < 60) {
                    return seconds + " second(s)";
                } else if (minutes < 60) {
                    return minutes + " minute(s)";
                } else if (hours < 24) {
                    return hours + " hour(s)";
                } else {
                    return days + " day(s)";
                }
            }

/* Note: In the line below, i listen to the unload event, you can change this event to a button click or anything else you want to listen to before calling the function. This is better than calling setInterval() every second and i think it will help your application performance also. */
            window.addEventListener('beforeunload', time_elapsed, false);
        </script>



</head>
<body>



</div>
</br>
</br>
</br>






<?php
echo $timeSpent  
?>
```

And the db.php:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=Windows-1250');    
$firstName = $_POST['firstname'];
    // DB connection
    $host = 'db.mysql-01.gsp-europe.net';
    $db_name = 'xxxx';
    $username = 'xxx';
    $password = 'xxxx';

   try {
     $conn = new PDO('mysql:host='.$host.';dbname='.$db_name, $username, $password);
     $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
   } catch (PDOException $e) {
     echo "Connection Error: " . $e->getMessage();
   }

    if (isset($_POST['timeSpent'])){
      $timeSpent = $_POST['timeSpent'];

      // create query
      $query = 'INSERT INTO user_time SET time = :time';

      // prepare statement
      $stmt = $conn->prepare($query);

      // bind data
      $stmt->bindParam(':time', $timeSpent);

      // execute query and check if it failed or not
      if ($stmt->execute()){
         echo "Query Successful";
      } else {
         printf("Error: %s.\n", $stmt->error);
      }
   }

?>
```

Comment: don't use `mysql_`-functions, they are deprecated for years and removed in php7. use `mysql_` or `PDO`. and use parameterised statements, your code is open to **SQL injection attacks**

Comment: Simply saying that something is "not working" is not a helpful problem statement.  What _is_ happening?  How does that differ from what you want?  What debugging have you already done?

Comment: @PatrickQ - Not working means, it doesnt save and load variables. Okey I edited the post with my current code .... And for now its not showing anything, and not saving anything ...

Comment: There's no function `mysql_`. It should be `mysql_query()`.

Comment: Check for errors `mysql_query(...) or die(mysql_error())`.

Comment: correct mysql_ it should be mysql_query();

Comment: if (mysql_error()) die('Error, insert query failed');. I edited my current code .. Still error

Comment: I edited ... Now i show you how im connected

Comment: You shouldn't connect with PDO and use mysql to run queries.

Comment: Okey , i will try msql connect

Comment: No, keep the PDO connection. I will provide an answer for you in a sec.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okey, i Got it.. Here is a code:

Timing PAGE:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=Windows-1250');    
$firstName = $_POST['firstname'];
session_start();

$_SESSION['firstname'] = $firstName;

?>


<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=Windows-1250" />
<title>Timing Stránka</title>


<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var auto_refresh = setInterval(
function ()
{
$('#load_tweets').load('db.php').fadeIn("slow");
}, 1000); // refresh every 10000 milliseconds
</script> 



</head>
<body>



</div>
</br>
</br>
</br>




<div id="load_tweets"> </div>  


Time on page: <label id="minutes">00</label>
<label id="colon">:</label>
<label id="seconds">00</label>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var minutesLabel = document.getElementById("minutes");
        var secondsLabel = document.getElementById("seconds");
        var totalSeconds = 0;
        setInterval(setTime, 1000);

        function setTime()
        {
            ++totalSeconds;
            secondsLabel.innerHTML = pad(totalSeconds%60);
            minutesLabel.innerHTML = pad(parseInt(totalSeconds/60));
        }

        function pad(val)
        {
            var valString = val + "";
            if(valString.length < 2)
            {
                return "0" + valString;
            }
            else
            {
                return valString;
            }
        }
    </script>

 <INPUT TYPE="button" onClick="history.go(0)" VALUE="Oprava">

</body>
</html>
```

The page of timing AKA db.php:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=Windows-1250');    
session_start();
$firstName = $_SESSION['firstname'];
$_SESSION['firstname'] = $firstName;



$servername = "db.xxxx.gsp-europe.net";
$username = "xxxxxx";
$password = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
$dbname = "xxxxx";






/// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection

 $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT points FROM member_profile WHERE user_id = '$firstName'");
$stmt->execute();
$array = [];
$resalts = $stmt->get_result();
while ($row = $resalts->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC))
{
    $points = $row['points'];
}

$hours = floor($points / 3600);
$mins = floor($points / 60 % 60);
$secs = floor($points % 60);







if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

// check if the user exist
$check = "SELECT * FROM `member_profile` WHERE user_id = '$firstName'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$check) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
        $rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
        //if exist increse points with 1
        if($rows>=1){

$sql = "UPDATE `member_profile` SET points = points + 1 WHERE user_id = '$firstName'";









if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "";
} else {
    echo "Error doing sum thingz: " . $conn->error;
}
        }
        //if don't exist create user with points 0
        if($rows==0)
        {
            $query = "INSERT into `member_profile` (user_id, points) VALUES ( '$firstName' ,'0')";

            $result = mysqli_query($conn,$query)or die(mysqli_error($conn));


$conn->close();

        }





?>


<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=Windows-1250" />








 </head>
<body>




</div>
</br>
Meno Užívateľa:   <b>  <?php echo $firstName; ?>    </b>
    </br>
    </br>
    Overall time :   <b> <?php echo $timeFormat = sprintf('%02d:%02d:%02d', $hours, $mins, $secs); ?>  </b>  

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please create two tables one table for saving two variables and another table to saving identificator. Then use foreign key and relationships with JOINS. Hope these steps will save your problem.

Comment: Can you please give me a some code ? Im totally amateur, and i dont know how to do it.. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Kindly replace the code in your "time.php" with this:

```
    <?php
    header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=Windows-1250');
    session_start();
    $firstName = $_SESSION['firstname'];
    $minutes = $_POST['minutes'];
    $seconds = $_POST['seconds'];

    // DB connection
    $host = 'localhost';
    $db_name = 'zadmin';
    $username = 'xxx';
    $password = 'zadmin_nahovno';

   try {
     $conn = new PDO('mysql:host='.$host.';dbname='.$db_name, $username, $password);
     $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
   } catch (PDOException $e) {
     echo "Connection Error: " . $e->getMessage();
   }

    // create query
    $query = 'INSERT INTO time SET meno = :firstName, minuty = :minutes, sekundy = :seconds';

    // prepare  statement
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($query);

    // bind data
    $stmt->bindParam(':firstName', $firstName);
    $stmt->bindParam(':minutes', $minutes);
    $stmt->bindParam(':seconds', $seconds);

    // execute query and check if it failed or not
    if ($stmt->execute()){
       echo "Query Successful";
    } else {
       printf("Error: %s.\n", $stmt->error);
    }

    ?>


/*
This should work (if not, then something is wrong with your variables, you should look into your variables and see if they are actually holding any data). You can make use of var_dump() to examine the variables.
*/
     Meno Užívateľa:   <b>  <?php echo $firstName; ?>    </b>
    </br>
    </br>
    Momentálne majníš :   <b> <?php echo $minutes; ?>  Minút  </b>    <b>   a   </b>   <b>   <?php echo $seconds; ?>  Sekúnd   </b>
     </br>
    </br>
```

Comment: You're missing an ' after :seconds

Comment: Its not working .... When i insert your code, the code under //not showing, is not showing

Comment: Do you get any errors. If you do, kindly share them.

Comment: Nothing, blank. When i only add onnect code :   mysql_connect('127.0.0.1','zadmin','xxx');
    mysql_select_db("zadmin_nahovno");. Its okey, but when i put full code, its only blank

Comment: I told you to keep the PDO connection, that's the best way to work with queries and avoid SQL Injection. You shouldn't have changed the connection from PDO to mysqli connection. I will edit my answer and re-write the whole time.php for you so you can just replace your code with mine

Comment: @HnusnyPleb, I updated the answer for you so you can try replacing your code with mine.

Comment: Okey, its working, but the name is ZERO, and the variables are not resuming. And one more thing. I have a very specifical code in previus PHP (i will edit post to show you), and it spamming my database (cuz its every time change the time value). But thank you

Comment: Okey, the names is working.. My badly configured table.... But it is not recovering the time, and it is spamming my table

Comment: Is there any way ,to create one line in table, and no saving whole variable, but only add +1 (to seconds) .... Because it is updating every second, it will be accurante .. Thank you. SOmething like:  $seconds+1 code

Comment: Ok, i think i get what you're trying to do. You are trying to get the number of time a user has spent on a page and store it in your db. I have never done this before so it will take me some time to come up with an algorithm of how to do this. But, in my opinion, i don't think you are doing it the right way. I will update my answer as soon as i come up with something

Comment: @HnusnyPleb have you been able to solve your problem or are you still waiting for any response from me?

Comment: Im waiting for response

Comment: Ok, i will post another answer about that for you

Answer (score 0):

@Hnusny Pleb, so in order to get the amount of time spent on a page, i wrote the following code for you.

First, in your script, you should write this:

```
        <script>
            let startTime, endTime;
            $(window).on('load', () => {
                startTime = new Date();
            });

            function time_elapsed() {
                endTime = new Date();
                let timeDiff = endTime - startTime;
                let timeSpent = timeConversion(timeDiff);
                const formData = new FormData();
                formData.append('timeSpent', timeSpent);

/* The line below is used to send data to the server-side. This way is reliable than using AJAX to send the data especially in cases when you are listening for an unload event. You can read more about navigator.sendBeacon() in MDN's site. */
                navigator.sendBeacon('index.php', formData);
            }

            function timeConversion(time) {
                let seconds = (time / 1000).toFixed(1);
                let minutes = (time / (1000 * 60)).toFixed(1);
                let hours = (time / (1000 * 60 * 60)).toFixed(1);
                let days = (time / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)).toFixed(1);
                if (seconds < 60) {
                    return seconds + " second(s)";
                } else if (minutes < 60) {
                    return minutes + " minute(s)";
                } else if (hours < 24) {
                    return hours + " hour(s)";
                } else {
                    return days + " day(s)";
                }
            }

/* Note: In the line below, i listen to the unload event, you can change this event to a button click or anything else you want to listen to before calling the function. This is better than calling setInterval() every second and i think it will help your application performance also. */
            window.addEventListener('beforeunload', time_elapsed, false);
        </script>
```

After writing the script above, the data will be sent to your server-side and then you can simply store the time spent (i.e. in seconds, minutes, hours or days) into your DB. In order to do that, you should write something similar to this in your server-side:

```
<?php
   if (isset($_POST['timeSpent'])){
      $timeSpent = $_POST['timeSpent'];

      // create query
      $query = 'INSERT INTO user_time SET time = :time';

      // prepare statement
      $stmt = $conn->prepare($query);

      // bind data
      $stmt->bindParam(':time', $timeSpent);

      // execute query and check if it failed or not
      if ($stmt->execute()){
         echo "Query Successful";
      } else {
         printf("Error: %s.\n", $stmt->error);
      }
   }
?>
```

Kindly find a way to use the written code to achieve your goals. I think ive tried my best in helping you. Good Luck.

Comment: Hello, thanks for reply, but im getting blank page (and only this error, when add echo variable :"Undefined variable: timeSpent .... " I edited post for current situation

Comment: Obviously, the variable is undefined because i didn't define it outside the if statement but inside the if statement. You should not place the ```echo $timeSpent``` outside the if statement, it should be located inside the if statement.

Comment: Okey, I edited my code, still issue with blank page on  database php, and variable not defined. Thanks